# Securing Private API keys in Javascript Web App

Tags: javascript, api, security, rest, authentication

## How can I securely store the keys to my private API in my web based (javascript) application?

I've thoroughly researched this but am yet to find a solid answer or any kind of standard procedure.

My API implements HMAC authentication, and every member of my site has a public/secret key to authenticate their use of the API and sign their request.

On a mobile app, the server would send the public/secret keys over an encrypted connection to be stored on the device after a successful login request. Subsequent requests would be signed using these keys.

So where should I store the keys on the client in this case, considering that the source code is visible to anyone who knows how to use a web inspector? In reality it's not an issue if the authenticated user sees their own keys, as they're unlikely to share them just like they'd be unlikely to share their account username/password with anyone else.

---

### Possible Solutions?

**Store the public/secret keys in cookies, and retrieve using javascript** - Probably not too secure, can the cookies be reliably cleared when the user logs out/their session ends?

**Store the public/secret keys in the web-page itself** - Only real solution I can think of - Javascript can access the keys through the DOM, and they can only be compromised(seen) if the user leaves their account logged in, and somebody knows where to look for them.

Note:
The web app is not a single-page app, so storing the public/secret keys within the memory is not an option.

---

**Not sure if i'm on the right track at all (something tells me I'm not), hopefully someone can set me straight on this.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've come to the conclusion that what i'm trying to protect against here is CSRF..

I'm using laravel, so my solution was to add the csrf nonce (Session::token()) in the head [as seen here](http://ericlbarnes.com/blog/single-page-laravel-app).

```
<meta name="token" content="32947fh2834fgkhgfr8724234f">
```

And send it along in the request header:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'session_token': '32947fh2834fgkhgfr8724234f' }
});
```

When authorising the api request it's a case of checking for the 'session_token' header and validating it's authenticity. If the session_token isn't there it'll fall back to the HMAC check.

Coupled with ssl this should be enough, Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there's a clear solution at all.  It sounds like you're trying to store a "secret" in a browser?  There will aways be a way to view it, even if you try to obfuscate it.

Comment: I guess so. I'm beginning to think the idea of a user uncovering their own keys in some way is not that dangerous. But the question of where to store the keys so that nobody other than the authorised user can see them is still relevant.

Comment: @thomasfw All you can guarantee to the best of your abilities is the secure delivery of the secrets to the target (i.e., the browser). Once they're there all bets are off, as it depends entirely how the client has secured his machine. If the machine is malware infested, you're pretty screwed.

Comment: @deceze What would you suggest? How about storing the public key in a cookie, and the private key in the document somewhere (similar to how a nonce can be generated inside a form).. <div id="keys" data-secret="{{api_secret}}"></div>. I can't believe there isn't a  procedure for this out there, how does Facebook authenticate on-site requests to it's API?

Comment: @thomasfw Public/private keys aren't widely used in browsers as far as I'm aware. Facebook et al typically use ephemeral tokens; i.e. good old session ids. At least those can be somewhat tied to the client using a number of additional sanity checks (IP, running counters, browser headers) and can be revoked.

Comment: @deceze So maybe the solution would be to have two authorisation procedures for my API - That way I can either send the HMAC signed requests from mobile/compiled apps, or bypass this procedure and confirm the request if a valid token is received in the header? Presumably also using ssl/tls to encrypt the connection would go some way in preventing the token from being compromised?

Answer (score -1):

Greeting,

Using API key and Token on the frontend applications always has a demand for storing key or token securely, unfortunately, the browser(client) has no such storage. This scenario can be overcome by using Access token (if Oauth) instead of API key after the authentication and these access token also can have their own expiration.

if really need an additional security against the stored Key/Token in the client side, In that case, we would have come up with a solution like encrypting our tokens using base64 kind of method with some hashing algorithm and decrypting and validating in the API endpoint would be the solution.

The following blog post may be helpful in this case:

https://www.wolfe.id.au/2012/10/20/what-is-hmac-authentication-and-why-is-it-useful/

Comment: @v8-E, Answer/Solution is given as a statement, the link was provided just for reference, not as an answer.

Comment: base64 is not an encryption, and when using any hashing algorithm, the token itself is not recoverable. Also, please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to external ressources